# Format the array output to display friendly names

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I've this function that returns a JSON response:

```
public function getUsersAction()
{
    $response = array();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository("UserBundle:User")->findAll();

    $roles = array(
        "ROLE_PROFILE_ONE" => "Facturación y Entrega",
        "ROLE_PROFILE_TWO" => "Envío",
        "ROLE_ADMIN" => "Administrador",
        "ROLE_USER" => "No posee roles asignados"
    );

    $users = array();
    foreach ($entities as $entity)
    {
        $user = array();

        $user[] = $entity->getUsername();
        $user[] = $entity->getEmailCanonical();
        $user[] = $entity->getRoles();
        $user[] = $entity->getGroupNames() != NULL ? $entity->getGroupNames() : "-";
        $users[] = $user;
    }

    $response[ 'data' ] = $users;
    return new JsonResponse($response);

}
```

I access it through Twig template via Ajax call, that's work! Now since `getRoles()` from `User` (FOSUser) model return the DB value as per example: `ROLE_PROFILE_ONE`, `ROLE_ADMIN`, `ROLE_USER`, how do I format the output to display friendly names based on `$roles` defined array? I tried to do a `foreach` loop inside the `foreach ($entities as $entity) ...` and set a new array but the nested calls is to big since my Apache goes down. Any help?

**Trying to be more clear with input/output example**

Well, this is what we have as input (what the function returns, I made a `ladybug_dump($entities)` to get the output):

```
array(6)
   [0]: object(Tanane\UserBundle\Entity\User)
      >> Properties
      ...
      # [roles]: array(1)
         [0]: string (16) "ROLE_PROFILE_ONE"
      ...
   [1]: object(Tanane\UserBundle\Entity\User)
      >> Properties
      ...
      # [roles]: array(2)
         [0]: string (16) "ROLE_PROFILE_TWO"
         [1]: string (16) "ROLE_PROFILE_ONE"
      ...
```

When I access that on Twig, at template, I got:

```
User1 ROLE_PROFILE_ONE
User2 ROLE_PROFILE_TWO, ROLE_PROFILE_ONE
```

But I need this output instead:

```
User1 Facturación y Entrega
User2 Envío, Facturación y Entrega
```

It's more clear now?

Comment: Does Symfony return stdClass array object or PHP assoc array

Comment: @NoahMatisoff an assoc array: `# [roles]: array(1) [0]: string (16) "ROLE_PROFILE_ONE"`

Comment: Please edit the op with the current array formatted properly and the output you want after the problem is solved.

Comment: @NoahMatisoff done, take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your roles are always going to transform to those specific string then you could add them to your user model and build a list of the roles in a `getTransformedRoles()` method like..

<kbd>User.php</kbd>

```
class User extends BaseUser implements UserInterface
{
    const ROLE_PROFILE_ONE = 'Facturación y Entrega';
    const ROLE_PROFILE_TWO = 'Envío';
    const ROLE_ADMIN       = 'Administrador';
    const ROLE_USER        = 'No posee roles asignados';
    ...
    public function getTransformedRoles()
    {
        $transformed = array();

        foreach ($this->getRoles() as $role) {
            $role = strtoupper($role);
            $const = sprintf('self::%s', $role);

            // Do not add if is $role === ROLE_USER
            if (FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface::ROLE_DEFAULT === $role) {
                continue;
            }

            if (!defined($const)) {
                throw \Exception(sprintf('User does not have the role constant "%s" set', $role));
            }

            $transformed[] = constant($const);
        )

        // If no roles add self::ROLE_USER
        if (empty($transformed)) {
            $transformed[] = self::ROLE_USER;
        }

        return $transformed;
    }
    ....
}
```

This would then return the fully transformed array of roles (using `$user->getTransformedRoles()`) where ever you may want them as opposed to just the single use case.

Alternatively you could do it with a service that does the same kind of transformation but with a set of varying roles and transformations that you could set via the config.yml.

**Update**

To use this as a service with your role transformations specified in your `app/config/config` you could do the following..

<kbd>Acme/SomethingBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration</kbd>

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('role_transformations')
            ->defaultValue(array())
            ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
                ->prototype('scalar')->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

<kbd>Acme/SomethingBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeSomethingExtension</kbd>

```
$container->setParameter(
    'acme.something.role_transformations', 
    $config['role_transformations']
);
```

Then in your <kbd>app/config/config.yml</kbd>

```
// For an empty array
role_transformations: ~ // Or not even at all, it defaults to an empty array
// For transformation
role_transformations:
    ROLE_PROFILE_ONE: 'Facturación y Entrega'
    ROLE_PROFILE_TWO: 'Envío'
    ROLE_ADMIN: 'Administrador'
    ROLE_USER: 'No posee roles asignados'
```

Create your service and inject the role_transformations

```
parameters:
    acme.something.role_transformer.class: Acme/SomethingBundle/Transformer/RoleTransformer

services:
    acme.something.role_transformer:
        class: %acme.something.role_transformer.class%
        arguments:
            - %acme.something.role_transformations%
```

Then in your service file (<kbd>Acme/SomethingBundle/Transformer/RoleTransformer</kbd>)

```
class RoleTransformer implements RoleTransformerInterface
{
    const ROLE_DEFAULT = 'ROLE_USER';
    protected $rolesTransformations;

    public function __construct(array $roleTransformations)
    {
        $this->roleTransformations = $roleTransformations;
    }

    public function getTransformedRolesForUser($user)
    {
        if (!method_exists($user, 'getRoles')) {
            throw new \Exception('User object has no "getRoles" method');
            // Alternatively you could add an interface to you user object specifying 
            // the getRoles method or depend on the Symfony security bundle and 
            // type hint Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface
        }

        return $this->getTransformedRoles($user->getRoles();
    }

    public function getTransformedRoles(array $roles)
    {
        $transformedRoles = array()

        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            $role = strtoupper($role);

            if (null !== $transformedRole = $this->getTransformedRole($role)) {
                $transformedRoles[] = $transformedRole;
            }
        }

        return $transformedRoles;
    }

    public function getTransformedRole($role)
    {
        if (self::ROLE_USER === $role) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!array_key_exists($role, $this->roleTransformations)) {
            throw \Exception(sprintf(
                'Role "%s" not found in acme.something.role_transformations', $role)
            );
        }

        return $this->roleTransformations[$role];
    }
}
```

This could be then be injected into a service or controller and used like

```
$transformer = $this->container->get('acme.something.role_transformer');
// Or injected via the DI

$roles = $transformer->getTransformedRolesForUser($user);
// For all of a users roles
$roles = $transformer->getTransformedRoles($user->getRoles());
// For an array of roles
$role = $transformer->getTransformedRole('ROLE_PROFILE_ONE');
// For a single role, or null if ROLE_USER
```

Comment: I like this solution and is what I'll use, now @Qoop I have a problem here and I forgot to mention in the main post, by default Symfony2 will always, or at least this is what I think, assign `ROLE_USER` so now in the transformed data I have strings like this `Envío,No posee roles asignados`, `Envío,Facturación y Entrega,No posee roles asignados` which is wrong since `No posee roles asignados` should appear only if no roles are assigned to user in which case the `ROLE_USER` should be use, did you have any idea in how to avoid this or fix this? BTW thanks for your answer

Comment: You could catch that special case in the `getTransformedRoles` method ("unless ROLE_USER is the only role, remove ROLE_USER from output"), or adjust the [Symfony role hierarchy](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles) so that ROLE_USER is not auto-assigned to everyone.

Comment: @Qoop in your answer you said this `Alternatively you could do it with a service that does the same kind of transformation but with a set of varying roles and transformations that you could set via the config.yml.` could you improve your answer with this solution too in order to give a alternative? Will be nice for newbies!!

Comment: I will do if I find the time.

Comment: I've updated. Its' not really checked through though so it might not be bang on.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you've tried to do a nested loop to create a new array, something like this?:

```
$users = array();
foreach ($entities as $entity)
{
    $user = array();

    $user[] = $entity->getUsername();
    $user[] = $entity->getEmailCanonical();

    $rolearray = [];
    foreach ($entity->getRoles() as $role)
    {
        $rolearray[] = $roles[$role];
    }
    $user[] = $rolearray;

    $user[] = $entity->getGroupNames() != NULL ? $entity->getGroupNames() : "-";
    $users[] = $user;
}
```

That's what I'd do.  You could use `array_map` instead, but I don't see why that would differ significantly.  It seems very unlikely this would be so resource intensive as to bring down the server, I would strongly suspect some other problem if that's happening.

Comment: Weird, is the same I did and it takes down my whole Apache server, anyway I'm trying @Qoop way but thanks to you too